# Releasing UIImageView and still getting a memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uiimageview

I have searched my best before posting this here. below is the code that is causing memory leak. Including autorelease fixes the memory leak but I am more interested in knowing what am I doing wrong here. If i own it, I should release it, which is what I am trying to do :)
THankyou for the help in advance. ContainerView is a UIView, and I am adding my welcome text to it.

```
UIImageView *welcomeText = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
welcomeText = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
welcomeText.frame = (CGRect) {  CGRectGetMidX(containerView.frame) -295 , 100.0, 590,134 };
welcomeText.autoresizingMask =  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | 
        UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
welcomeText.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"welcome-to-the-jungle.png"];
[containerView addSubview:welcomeText];
[welcomeText release];
```

Comment: "Including autorelease fixes the memory leak", do you mean that you are autoreleasing the image view and calling the release on it? (BTW, funny pic name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UIImageView *welcomeText = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
welcomeText = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

After the 2nd line previously alloced welcomeText is lost and you are leaking that memory. After 1st line an image view is alloced and welcomeText is pointing to that. In 2nd line another image view is alloced and now welcomeText is pointing to this new one. So you don't have any pointer to 1st alloced image view and as a result that is leaked.

Here you don't need the 1st line actually.

```
UIImageView *welcomeText = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Answer (score 0):

You must not allocate an UIImageView object in the first line. In the second line, the object allocated in the first line leaks.